# Create custom page view counter in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to create my own view counter. I got inspired from `django-hitcount`. I read all models of this app.

In these lines:

```
class HitCountMixin(object):
    """
    HitCountMixin provides an easy way to add a `hit_count` property to your
    model that will return the related HitCount object.
    """

    @property
    def hit_count(self):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__)
        hit_count, created = HitCount.objects.get_or_create(
            content_type=ctype, object_pk=self.pk)
        return hit_count
```

I couldn't understand the meaning  and usage of `ContentType` and `get_for_model(self.__class__)`. **Can anyone help me?** 
Source of this mixin is [here](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/develop/hitcount/models.py#L186-L197).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `HitCountMixin` can be inherited by different models in your app, `HitCount` model must be in some way connected to these models with a relation.
Here you can think of `ContentType` as a way of creating dynamic relation unlike it is with e.g. `ForeignKey` where you are bound to use the relation only with one model (table).

`get_for_model` is just Django's helper method for getting ContentType instance for given model because each model (table) would have its corresponding `ContentType` instance.

With example model using this mixin:

```
class Example(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    pass
```

`ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__)` would return `ContentType` instace for model `Example`

You can read more about ContentTypes in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)